# error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8 in ecplise

Tags: maven, selenium, character-encoding, testng

please check for below code have set maven compiler plugin when trying to run maven build...clean install im facing this issue.

```
  [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] \Users\CreditCardClass.java:[168,31] error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

pom.xml file with fallowing code

```
      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      </properties>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

I have set UFT-8 IN properties->Resource->test file UTF-8 .Please can any one answer this

Comment: seems like `CreditCardClass.java` contains invalid characters. Wihich Editor/IDE do you use?

Comment: what's at `[168,31]` in CreditCardClass.java?

Comment: i am getting error for all class just i posted 1 line of error,     and i have added <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: okay , thanks Wurgspa and Kiril, because of your point i got to know this issue.